# Use JavaScript Code to run Puppeteer from Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, controller, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to launch a browser from a laravel controller, however i don't know how to run the JavaScript code from the controller

My function looks like this:

```
$script = <<<SCRIPT
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('http://my-url.com');
        const button = await page.$('button#button');
        await button.evaluate( button => button.click() );
        await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
        ...
        await browser.close();
    })();
    SCRIPT;
$process = new Process(['node', '-e', $script]);
$process->run();
$output = $process->getOutput();
```

When i try to run just this part of the code in the node shell:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});     
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://my-url.com');
    const button = await page.$('button#button');
    await button.evaluate( button => button.click() );
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    ...
    await browser.close();
})();
```

it works fine and I can also see a browser being opened. When I try to run the whole function it doesn't work. SO I presume that the way i'm running the JS code in the controller is wrong.

Comment: Well, i think you can use the puppeteer-core package, which is a version of Puppeteer that doesn't come bundled with Chromium. This allows you to use Puppeteer with an existing installation of Chrome or Chromium.

Comment: I have puppeteer-core installed, puppeteer@19 already includes puppeteer-core in its package. In the node shell the js code works perfectly, but i was wondering why the same code doesn't work the way i wrote it in the controller as php

Comment: The reason your code is not working as expected when executed from within the PHP controller is that you are attempting to execute a Node.js script using the Process class in PHP. I will post an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new js File for the JavaScript Code `script.js`

```
// script.js

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});     
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://my-url.com');
    const button = await page.$('button#button');
    await button.evaluate( button => button.click() );
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    ...
    await browser.close();
})();
```

And in the controller i have changed:

```
$process = new Process(['path/to/node', 'path/to/script.js]);
$process->run();
if(!$process->isSuccessful()) {
  throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
$output = $process->getOutput();
$errors = $process->getErrorOutput();
```

That worked for me